# What do you call a set of protruding bars, some mobile, some not, which are used to carry a load and manipulate it?

Tags: word-request

> I loaded a huge chainsaw on my * and off of it.

I am not sure if there are words for such a thing. I am thinking of a set of bars that can be used to hold heavy objects with mobile bars like arms that are used to manipulate the heavy objects in order to drop or load these objects off and on the set of immobile bars.

Comment: Are you asking about something like this device that helps with moving around heavy things in a specific area? https://images.app.goo.gl/8mxeCfDCLmoYnArX9

Comment: some kind of gripper used with a crane?

Comment: Something you can wear and transport heavy objects with it.

Comment: Perhaps you can find what you are looking for if you google *exoskeleton suit*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a very specific term, but such a thing could be called a "rack". If you have such a thing, you might look at the instructions and see what the manufacturer calls it. If you cna find where one is for sale, online or offline, again see what term the seller uses.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a portable rack you can wear?

Answer (score 2):

This equipment is called a forklift.

Wikipedia presents the equipment in [this article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forklift).

Comment: I did not understand the OP to be describing a forklift. If that was the intent, then I badly misunderstood. I thought this was some sort of un-powered stand or rolling-rack.

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was trying to describe.